# How do I import this file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mysqlimport

I'm trying to import [this Hungarian text file](http://www.cometapps.com/share/hu_50K.zip) into a MySQL table but the Hungarian characters are always corrupted. I've tried many encodings for both the import file and table haven't found the right combination.

The file format is one word and one number per line, separated by a space. My import table has two columns, varchar and integer. I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 and phpMyAdmin 3.4.5. phpMyAdmin solution is preferred but I can use the command line if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Broken link above fixed

Comment: you can look at the previously mentioned [SO Solution]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763770/export-and-import-utf8-data-in-mysql-best-practices)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help. I've tried many flavors of UTF-8.

Comment: **More information required.**  What do you mean by "*characters are always corrupted*"?  How are you trying to import the file?  `mysqlimport`?  `LOAD DATA`?  Parsing in application code then invoking `INSERT`?  When importing via phpMyAdmin there is a drop-down through which one specifies the "Character set of the file"... do you have that set correctly?  What are the character sets of the columns into which text are inserted?  How have you determined that any corruption took place during insertion and not during retrieval?

Comment: I'm using CSV with LOAD DATA. The corruption depends on which encoding I'm trying. I don't know the character set of the file or how to find that out. I've tried many different character sets for the import column and cannot list them all here.

Comment: I'd download your file to try and help identify its character set, but the link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file appears to be encoded in UTF-8.  For example:

```
$ unzip -p hu_50K.zip | sed -n 59p | xxd
0000000: 6bc3 b673 7ac3 b66e c3b6 6d20 3532 3030  k..sz..n..m 5200
0000010: 310d 0a                                  1..
```

I understand that "*köszönöm*" is Hungarian for "*thank you*".  If that is what row 59 of the file is supposed to contain, then the `ö` character (U+00F6) is encoded as `0xc3b6`, [which is](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f6/charset_support.htm) UTF-8.

To import this file using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

```sql
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE '/path/to/hu_50K.txt'
    INTO TABLE my_table
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ' '
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (col_word, col_number)
```

Of course, `col_word` must be able to hold the characters - which it necessarily will if it is also encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you very much! Before I try your solution, can you recommend how to define the word column in the import table? Does it matter which collation or other attributes I use?

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I honestly think the problem was with the import plugin in phpMyAdmin because I'm sure I already tried it with UTF-8. From now on I will use the command line for imports. Thanks again! (and again!)

Answer (score 0):

try this solution to convert file to utf-8

```
import codecs 
import commands 
f_loc = "my.file"
f_enc = commands.getoutput('file -b --mime-encoding %s' % f_loc)
 f_stream = codecs.open(f_loc, 'r', f_enc) 
f_out = codecs.open(f_loc+"b", 'w', 'utf-8') 
for l in f_stream: 
     f_output.write(l) 
 f_stream.close() 
 f_out.close()
```

once this is done you can use this file to load into mysql using [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) .

Also ensure that CHARACTER SET clause of the LOAD DATA INFILE is set to The encoding of the file as it can override  character_set_database system variable